# Interface Builder with predefined constant values

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Is it possible to use predefined constant values in Interface Builder?

eg. If I define `MyConstantWidth = 10;` in a header file, can I then use it in IB? I expect it doesn't work but maybe somebody has a clever solution.

Comment: Create an outlet and in your .m, set it to that constant from .h

Comment: I am trying to avoid the outlet if possible and keep it all in IB.

Comment: In that case one voteup for your question...I dont know whether this is possible or not.

Comment: generally speaking, maybe it is easier to work with _designable_ views, then you can set up custom properties in the IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Interface Builder is a one-way ticket.

You can only feed the .m with information (via runtime attributes) and you can't use info from your .m/.h to feed the IB.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, placing values in your code to use in IB goes against the whole idea of separating visuals from the coded logic.

I do recognize that using "named" values within IB would be helpful to maintain consistency and facilitating updates.  Colors are my personal pet peeve on this front.

If you aim to programatically change attributes that merely have an initial value in IB, outlets are probably your only option.

You can also use a hidden controls or low priority constraints to express an arbitrary value that you map to via an outlet.  I use that sometimes to toggle between constraint values by creating two additional low priority constraints and copying their .constant value to the high priority one when appropriate.  This keeps all the values in IB and close to each other (and more importantly out of the code).